# Dynamic sub domains using mod rewrite and htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok I have tried multiple examples of this from various places but just can't seem to get it working. Maybe I'm missing something here...

- I have wildcard sub domains enabled already by using *.example.com (it's pointed at the public_html folder)
- The sub domains I need to load are located in a folder called users, for example the structure would be example.com/users/testuser, I need to call testuser.example.com and have it load what resides in the testuser folder (will be a index.php file).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^users/([a-z0-9\-_\.]+)/?(.*)$ http://$1.example.com/$2 [QSA,NC,R,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by using the following link:

http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Dynamic_Subdomains

The way I structured this:

public_html/subdomains

public_html/.htaccess

public_html/viewSubdomain.php

The code below was pulled from the above link.

.htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^subdomains/(.*)/(.*) http://$1.example.com/$2 [r=301,nc]

# Fix missing trailing slashes.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2%{REQUEST_URI}/ -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# Rewrite sub domains.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]

#Choose one of the following lines:
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomains/%2/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewSubdomain.php?subdomain=%2&file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

viewSubdomain.php (Replace username and example.com with your info on line 4)

```
<?php
set_time_limit(20);
$fileTypes = array('index.php','index.html','index.htm');
$file = '/home/username/example.com'; //replace this info with your path
$err = FALSE;
if(isset($_GET['file'])){
    if(!file_exists($file.'/subdomains/'.$_GET['subdomain'].'/index.php')){
        if(!file_exists($file.'/subdomains/'.$_GET['subdomain'].'/index.html')){
            if(!file_exists($file.'/subdomains/'.$_GET['subdomain'].'/index.htm')){
                $err = TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    if(empty($_GET['file'])&&file_exists($file.'/subdomains/'.$_GET['subdomain'].'/index.php')){
        $f = 'index.php';
        $s = 'index.php';
    }
    elseif(empty($_GET['file'])&&file_exists($file.'/subdomains/'.$_GET['subdomain'].'/index.htm')){
        $f = 'index.htm';
        $s = 'index.htm';
    }
    elseif(empty($_GET['file'])&&file_exists($file.'/subdomains/'.$_GET['subdomain'].'/index.html')){
        $f = 'index.html';
        $s = 'index.html';
    }else{
        $s = $_GET['file'];
        $f = $_GET['file'];
        $err = FALSE;
    }
}else{
    $f = $_GET['file'];
    $s = $_GET['file'];
}
$file .= '/subdomains/'.$_GET['subdomain'].'/'.$f;
if(file_exists($file)&&!$err){
    if(preg_match("~^(.*).(css|js|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|swf)$~",$file,$matches)){
        if($matches[2]=='css'){
            header("Content-type: text/css");
        }elseif($matches[2]=='js'){
            header("Content-type: text/javascript");
        }elseif($matches[2]=='jpeg'){
            header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
        }elseif($matches[2]=='jpg'){
            header("Content-type: image/jpg");
        }elseif($matches[2]=='gif'){
            header("Content-type: image/gif");
        }elseif($matches[2]=='png'){
            header("Content-type: image/png");
        }elseif($matches[2]=='swf'){
            header("Content-type: application/x-shockwave-flash");
        }
        readfile($file);
    }else{
        include $file;
    }
}else{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

}
?>
```